# Do squadmates with the squadmate ammo upgrade grant you the power?

Tags: mass-effect-3

If I upgrade a squadmate's ammo power and choose the "squadmate ammo" bonus in level 4, will I and the third squadmate get the ammo at 50% effectiveness? If so, and more importantly, can ammo bonuses be stacked if both squadmates and I have different ammo bonuses with the squadmate ammo upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the squadmate ammo bonuses are not stackable. The ammo power which was utilized the latest will override the effects of any previous one - regardless of whether the powers were the same or not. So in your case, I believe that you'll be able to apply that +50% boost to ammo power to all three of your squadmates. Only once though.